# C - Counting words in a string

Tags: c, string

i've been trying to do a function that counts the number of words in a string in C. However, in some casas (as the one in the example) it should return 0 and not 1... any ideas of what could be wrong?

```
#import <stdio.h>  

int contaPal(char s[]) {          
    int r;     
    int i;     
    r = 0;      

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {          
        if (s[i] == '\n')           
            r = r + 0;               

        if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i + 1] == ' ' && s[i + 1] != '\0')             
            r++;        

        if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i + 1] == '\0') {              
            r++;        
        }       
    }          
    return r; 
}  

int main () {   
    char s[15] = { ' ', '\n', '\0' };

    printf("Words: %d \n", (contaPal(s)));
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: @João Pimentel  Define the notion of the word.

Comment: @João Pimentel  If the new line is encountered then r is increased due to this condition if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i + 1] == '\0') { . So the function will return at least 1 for the string you defined.

Comment: at `if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i + 1] == '\0') {` : `('\n' != ' ' && '\0' == '\0')`  become true.

Comment: Don't check blank characters one by one, you have many of them and this complicates your task(`' ', '\t', '\n', '\r'`), use `isspace` from `ctype.h`.

Comment: r = r + 0?  heh :)

Comment: Also `s[i + 1] == ' ' && s[i + 1] != '\0'` : `&& s[i + 1] != '\0'` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should not treat `'\n'` differently from any other whitespace character.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <ctype.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  

int contaPal(const char *s) {          
    int count = 0, hassep = 1;

    while (*s) {
        if (isspace((unsigned char)*s) {
            hassep = 1;
        } else {
            count += hassep;
            hassep = 0;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void) {   
    char s[] = " \n";

    printf("Words: %d\n", contaPal(s));
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the word is any sequence of characters excluding white space characters.

Your function returns 1 because for the supplied string when the new line character is encountered the variable `r` is increased due to this condition

```
    if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i + 1] == '\0') {              
        r++;        
    }
```

So the function implementation is wrong.

It can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t contaPal( const char s[] ) 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *s )
    {
        while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
        n += *s != '\0';
        while ( *s && !isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
    }

    return n;
}  

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = { ' ', '\n', '\0' };

    printf( "Words: %zu\n", contaPal( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output as you expect is

```
Words: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple illustration using existing character test functions:

```
int main(void)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    int numWords = 0;
    BOOL trap = 0; //start count only after seeing a word
    char *sentence = "This is a sentence, too long.";       
    //char *sentence2 = "      ";//tested for empty string also


    while (*sentence != '\0') 
    {
        if ( isalnum (*sentence) ) //word is found, set trap and start count
        {
            sentence++;  //alpha numeric character, keep going
            trap = 1;
        }
        else if ( (( ispunct (*sentence) ) || ( isspace(*sentence) )) && trap)
        {  //count is started only after first non delimiter character is found
            numWords++;
            sentence++;
            while(( ispunct (*sentence) ) || ( isspace(*sentence) ))
            { //handle sequences of word delimiters
                sentence++;
            }
        }
        else //make sure pointer is increased either way
        {
            sentence++;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow -  I did not implement a function, it is a code snippet illustrating how to use additional char test functions `ispunct` and `isspace`.  To which funcntion are you referring please.  I did test this in a small main function by the way.

Comment: In any case the code snippet is a part of a function is not it? It is wrong.

Comment: What would be the outcome for a sentence containing only whitespaces?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - still not sure to what you are referring, but re-wrote to include `main()`, surrounding rest of snippet.  Does this address your concern?

Comment: @ryyker For an empty string the outcome will not be equal to 0.

Comment: @A.S.H - ah!  thank you.  Mis-count by one.  I need to test for at least one non delimiter before starting the count.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
    if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i + 1] == ' ' && s[i + 1] != '\0')             
        r++;
```

Exactly matches the case when you look on `'\n'`.

You should use `if ... else if ...`.